# getting volume with given region and bounds

Tags: integration, volume

So in my text book(online) we have this question and I'm very lost what to do as my answer is wrong.

The region bounded by the curve $y=x^2$  and the x-axis between $x = 1$ and $x = 0$  is revolved around the line $y = 1$ . Find the volume of this solid of revolution.

What I got was: $$\pi\cdot\int_0^1\left(1-\sqrt{y}\right)^2dy$$

Though it says its wrong.